# What is $\nu$ in this equation regarding phases of anyons under exchange?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, notation, topological-phase, anyons

From the [Quantiki article](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/anyons) on anyons:

> After exchanging two identical particles the quantum mechanics predicts that the wave function gain a phase factor:
> $$
> \Psi\to e^{i\theta}\Psi
> $$
>
> - For bosons $θ = 0$
> - For fermions $θ = π$
> - For anyons $θ = 2π\nu^{-1}$
>
> The structure of the excitation spectrum is efficiently described in terms of a gauge theory and Aharanov-Bohm gauge interactions.

What does $\nu$ represent here? Frequency? Or is it angular frequency?

Comment: Just some number.

Comment: For quantum hall with filling faction $\nu^{-1}$, the phase one gets when exchanging two anyons of electric charge $1/\nu$ is $\theta=\pi/\nu$.